# get index array of minimum value in an array and if there are some same minimum number check them with another same length array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array:

```
    array_A= [6, 8, 3, 3] // this array has two same minimum number.(3, 3 for example)
    array_B= [4, 5, 6, 7] // this array has not same numbers always.
```

I want to get the index of the minimum number of array_A, while array_A has two same min then I want to check these two number with array_B in the same place index, (for example first 3 by: 6 and second 3 by: 7) and as the minimum of (6 , 7) is 6 then give us the true index which is for first 3 in array_A.

I try many times by min function in php but its a big problem. this problem has to be general.
thanks.

Comment: So put your try with the question first :)

Comment: if I put any code here it will complicated more my question! its something like sorting an array-based another array that I can't find any way to solve ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks not complicated :)
Here is one of solutions

```
$a1= [6, 8, 3, 3];
$a2= [4, 5, 6, 7];
$keys = array_keys($a1, min($a1));
foreach($keys as $key){
    $res[] = $a2[$key];
}
echo min($res);
```

Comment: thanks, but it returns 6 ! while i want to get the index of array_A where first 3 is there.

Comment: `echo $keys[0];` or `echo min($keys)`

Comment: i add: $keys = array_keys($a2, min($res)); and it solved :) thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pack` to build 32 bits keys (16 from array A + 16 from array B) of a new array. Then I sort the array by key and extract the value of the smallest:

```
$arrA= [6, 8, 3, 3];
$arrB= [4, 5, 6, 7];

$arr=[];
foreach ($arrA as $k => $v) {
    $arr[pack("nn", $v, $arrB[$k])] = $k;
}

krsort($arr);

echo array_pop($arr);
```